# Join table with non-primary key in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to retrieve the information of an author based on a field in `BookData` that is not a primary key. Below you can see I have `AuthorId` in my `BookData` table and I am trying to get the author based on that `AuthorId` even though it is not the primary key. It seems GORM does not support this type of join, is there a way to do this?

You can also see below that I am able to properly get the `PublisherProperty` information because it's foreign key is `BookData`'s primary key. I am just wondering how to do it if it not the primary key. Thanks in advance!

```
type BookData struct {
    Id                string              `gorm:"primary_key;column:book_id"`
    AuthorId          string              `gorm:"column:author_id"`
    Author            AuthorData          `gorm:"foreignkey:AuthorId"`
    PublisherProperty []PublisherProperty `gorm:"foreignkey:Id"`
}

type AuthorData struct {
    Id    string `gorm:"primary_key;column:author_id"`
    Name  string `gorm:"column:author_name"`
}


type PublisherProperty struct {
    Id           string `gorm:"primary_key;column:book_id"`
    PublisherId  string `gorm:"primary_key;column:publisher_id"`
    PublisherTxt string `gorm:"column:publisher_txt"`
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword of `ForeignKey` and `References`. For more use cases can refer to the [official documentation of GORM](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html)

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

type BookData struct {
    Id                string              `gorm:"primary_key;column:book_id"`
    AuthorId          string              `gorm:"column:author_id"`
    Author            AuthorData          `gorm:"ForeignKey:Id;References:AuthorId"`
    PublisherProperty []PublisherProperty `gorm:"ForeignKey:Id"`
}

type AuthorData struct {
    Id   string `gorm:"primary_key;column:author_id"`
    Name string `gorm:"column:author_name"`
}

type PublisherProperty struct {
    Id           string `gorm:"primary_key;column:book_id"`
    PublisherId  string `gorm:"primary_key;column:publisher_id"`
    PublisherTxt string `gorm:"column:publisher_txt"`
}

var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    dsn := "user:pass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/temp?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    var books []BookData
    err := db.Preload("Author").Preload("PublisherProperty").
        Find(&books).Limit(10).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(books)
    // output:
    // [{1 1 {1 author1} [{1 1 } {1 2 }]} {2 1 {1 author1} []}]
}
```

[image]